# How to show Tab Bar when push notification arrives

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, apple-push-notifications

[image: Landing Screen]In my project there is tab bar for navigation between different views.

**When I receive push notification and viewing the push from notification panel my tab bar gets disappear.** 
I have to restart my app to view the tab bar again.

I have tried with this but did not work.

`self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=NO;`

Whenever notification arrives it goes directly to Value Screen And when I move back to Landing Screen tab bar disappears.

Comment: What are you using to present the push notification?

Comment: Using navigationView Controller to one of the View Controller.

Comment: Post some code, guesswork is not fun and we don't have the crystal ball.

Comment: Updated my Ques.

Comment: You attached a screenshot of your home, there is no error there and we still don't know how you **viewing the push from notification panel**, paste some code too.

Answer (score 0):

In your class, call like this

```
 init() {
 self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
 }

 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
 self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Write bellow code in your class.

```
 -(BOOL)hidesBottomBarWhenPushed
 {
   return NO;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
YourTabBarController *tabb = (YourTabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
}
```